# Cantor-Bendixson derivative sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I try to show that a compact subset   $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ is at most countable if and only if there exists a countable ordinal number $\alpha$ (i.e $\alpha <\omega_{1},$ where $\omega_{1}$ is  the first uncountable ordinal) such that  $\mbox{acc}^{\alpha}\,A=\emptyset;$ where $\mbox{acc}^{\alpha}\,A$ is the  Cantor-Bendixson derivative set defined by: \
$$ \begin{cases}
       \mbox{acc}^{0}\,A=A\\
       \mbox{acc}^{\alpha}\,A=\mbox{acc}^{\alpha-1}\,(\mbox{acc}\,A) \text{ if  $\alpha$ is a successor   ordinal.}\\
       \mbox{acc}^{\lambda}\,A=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}\mbox{acc}^{\alpha}\,A \text{ if  $\lambda$  is a limit ordinal.}
       \end{cases}
$$
Where $\mbox{acc}\,A$ is the set of all accumulation points of $A.$  Is this equivalence hold?

Please direct me to a book or to an article that discusses the Cantor-Bendixson derivative set in detail.

Comment: The point is that there is $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $acc^\alpha(A)=acc^{\alpha+1}(A)$ and that for this $\alpha$, $acc^\alpha(A)$ is perfect. Since perfect compact subsets of $\Bbb C$ are uncountable, this shows that $acc^\alpha(A)$ is empty for countable $A$. For the other direction you need that if $A$ is uncountable, then it contains an uncountable perfect set. This is all in early chapters of Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti . Also, if $A$ is any uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ then $A$ has a subset  $B$ such that $A$ \ $B$ is countable and $acc(B)\supset B.$